# Get all messages from a queue in RabbitMQ in c#

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Given the queue name, i need all the messages in that queue in RabbitMQ.

I have got the number of messages in the queue in msgCount variable and the first message in strBody variable.
But i need all the messages in the given queue. Something that the RabbitMQ Management UI gives me in the browser when i click the **Get Message(s)** button

```
using (var conn = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = conn.CreateModel())
            {
                var queueName = "myqueuename";

                var response = channel.QueueDeclarePassive(queueName);
                var msgCount = response.MessageCount;
                var consCount = response.ConsumerCount;

                BasicGetResult result = channel.BasicGet(queueName, noAck);


                if (result == null)
                {
                    //No msgs available 
                }
                else
                {
                    IBasicProperties properties = result.BasicProperties;
                    byte[] body = result.Body;

                    string strBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    Console.WriteLine(strBody);
                    //channel.BasicAck(result.DeliveryTag, false);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a simple http request to the rabbitMQ server does the job.
Make a POST request to the following url:

```
string queuesUrl = Url + ":" + Port + "/api/queues/" + VirtualHost + "/" + queueName + "/get";
```

where Url is where your rabbitMQ is hosted

Send the following payload

```
{"count":5,"ackmode":"ack_requeue_true","encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}
```

Put -1 in count to get all the messages. Truncate is optional

RabbitMQ Management HTTP API :
https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.8.0/priv/www/api/index.html

Comment: how do you send the payload. you didnt explain more then the documentation which doesnt tell you how to include the body.